# outputting multiple data frames to multiple excel files using loop in R

Tags: r

I am using the `xlsx` package in R and have a loop set up where many data frames are created and am having trouble writing the code to output each data frame from an iteration of the loop to a separately named excel file ..below is what I am trying to do..

```
data1 <- function(58) # Cannot disclose the function
write.xlsx(data.frame(data1),"data1.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1")

data2 <- function(59) 
write.xlsx(data.frame(data2),"data2.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1")

data1 <- function(60)
write.xlsx(data.frame(data3),"data3.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet1")
```

Comment: You should also post the code with  what you have attempted..

Comment: what is function here ?

Comment: Do you need it as separate excel file or separate sheet in same excel file ?

Comment: Hi I cannot give the function in detail since its work related. Function just returns an output that I can get in a data frame and then output onto excel. I need them in separate excel files but am also interested in seeing how to get them all in one excel file as separate sheets.

Comment: I can repeat what I have above by hand in R but there's a lot of excel files so I just need to see how to use looping to put each one in a different named excel file

Answer (score 1):

To save them as separate excel file using a loop

```
 for(i in seq_along(df.list)) {
   write.xlsx(df.list[[i]], paste(names(df.list)[i], ".xlsx"))
 }
```

To append as separate sheet in same excel sheet

```
 for(i in seq_along(df.list)) {
   write.xlsx(df.list[[i]], "Final.xlsx", sheetName=paste(names(df.list)[i]), append=TRUE)
 }
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(3,2,1),y=c(6,5,4))
df.list<-list(df1,df2) # make a list of the dataframes
names(df.list)<-c("DF1","DF2") # if they don't have names, create names
```

Comment: Where should I enter the `filepath` in `for(i in seq_along(df.list)) {
   write.xlsx(df.list[[i]], paste(names(df.list)[i], ".xlsx"))
 }` ?

Comment: append  it to the file name using `here::here(paste(names(df.list)[i], ".xlsx"))`

Comment: Like this `here::here(paste(names(df.list)[i], "filename.xlsx"))`?